# Data duplication in Detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a *Group* band with *Detail* band between the *Group header* and *Group footer*. The report is supposed to print multiple student examination records at once. I have grouped them according to the registration numbers. It works except for the fact that query results are shown twice.

as shown

```
    Student 1
    Subject    score

    Maths      50
    English    60
    kiswahili  70
    Maths      50
    English    60
    kiswahili  70

    Student 2
    Subject    score

    Maths      90
    English    60
    kiswahili  60
    Maths      60
    English    60
    kiswahili  60
```

insted of

```
    Subject    score

    Maths      50
    English    60
    kiswahili  70


    Student 2
    Subject    score

    Maths      90
    English    60
    kiswahili  60
```

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml* file?

Comment: actually i have figured out but cant solve yet. i inner joined 3 tables and i think its querrying twice. this is the query: select * from student_exam s inner join student_pos p on p.admno=s.admno inner join student register r on r.admno=s.admno

Answer (score 1):

Add an ORDER BY to the end of your query:

```
 ORDER BY registration_number, subject
```

Your data should be sent to the report template in the order in which it will be displayed. Order by student and then by subject.